Are French citizens banned by their government from entering the Darien gap, or do they need authorization by the French gov to enter the Darien gap?
I read some comments questioning whether the French government bans their citizens from entering the Darien gap (a region of the connection between the north and south American continents). Are French citizens banned by the French government from entering the Darien gap, or do they need some kind of authorization by the French government to enter the Darien gap?

Travel advice from governments, discouraging their citizens to travel to certain areas, are not 'travel bans' or situations where permission must be granted.

@MarkJohnson thanks, does that mean that French citizens are not banned by their government from entering the Darian gap, and they do not need any authorization by the French gov to enter the Darian gap?

Go to the french government travel advice and look for yourself.

@MarkJohnson but as you've said travel advice doesn't imply travel ban. Where's the ban list, if any?

I think we can infer from @MarkJohnson's comments, even though he does not mention it explicitly, that he is counting on the common sense assumption that the travel advice would also mention a ban or prohibition explicitly if there were one.  The absence of explicit mention of a ban or prohibition therefore implies that no ban or prohibition exist, even if there is a warning.

@phoog I don't believe in Germany that there is a legal basis to impose an absolute ban.

@phoog agreed, but at the time of my reply, I was unaware of any travel advice from the French government.

To build up on Giacomo Catenazzi's answer, it's interesting to note that somewhere between 2015 and 2016, the wording on the official website changed from les voyages sont à proscrire ("trips are to be avoided at all costs") to les voyages sont proscrits (travelling is prohibited).
I don't know if it reflects a change in ministry doctrine and/or answers a legal concern. The old phrasing seems more logical and was not at odds with the other parts of the site as mentioned by Giacomo.
However, about the Darien region specifically, the official French ministry page says travelling is discouraged, not explicitly banned.
You get some hints of the legal consequences of the red rank in this article in Le Figaro:

Repatriation costs no longer covered by the government if the traveller knowingly put themselves in a dangerous situation.
(inferred from question 7/) Travel agencies and airlines operating from France stop their connections with the red zone. Whether they naturally do it of their own volition, obey to transport sector rules or are formally asked to by Foreign Affairs is not clear, but the legal risk towards their customers should they continue operating is probably too high anyway.

The French law is based on freedom of movement in accordance with international treaties, however there's obviously a series of exceptions that restrict the right to travel in some cases - pandemic, travelling to terrorist-controlled zones and back, etc.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It can be a can of worms, because we are talking about foreign affairs and diplomacy, so they may uses friendly terms, and so interpretation is difficult.
In any case, we have the FAQ 6: https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/foire-aux-questions/#sommaire_6

Rouge : la zone est formellement déconseillée. Les voyages sont proscrits.

which translate: red: the zone is formally discouraged. Travels are banned, which seems using two contradictory terms.
So, let's check the two countries:
Panama: https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays-destination/panama/#securite, so you see Darian is in red region.
Colombia: https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays-destination/colombie/#securite also in red regions (and the red regions are much larger).
So travels are in some sort banned for French citizen. I have no idea on consequences: I do not think you can be imprisoned, or get a fine, but that may go on legal SE.

Thanks, great find! They're using using two contradictory terms indeed, good job. I'm betting it's discouraged but not banned. What's the legal consequence of going to a banned area?

I think in practice these travel advice only impacts insurances and consular assistance.

@FranckDernoncourt does proscrire always indicate a formal prohibition in French?

I guess that there would be no penalty back home.  I doubt that you be arrested as you get off the plane in CDG.  However, if you get into trouble then they might not try very hard to help.  Also, any travel insurance that you have might be invalidated if you are travelling against your government's advice.

@phoog afaik yes

@André: I think yes in this case. Other countries may have stricter enforcement (e.g. Israeli citizens cannot go on some villages, and that is old, also on calmer periods), or in case of war zones (not to enter in diplomatic problems). -- In any case, to confirm part of your assertion: the orange zone recommend to give travel plans to embassy (and do travel only in case of necessity). Red zone: they do not care any more about your plans.

@FranckDernoncourt: could you check the point 9 of the FAQ, and the cited law, and maybe translate to us. The law may be more explicit on the ban.

@GiacomoCatenazzi the law only contains 2 articles concerning travel, both about who reimburses the repatriation costs, one defines the responsibility of the tourist and the other that of the tour operator/transporter. https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/loda/id/LEGISCTA000022522645

@phoog from other comments/answers, sounds like I was wrong and that proscrire does not always indicate a formal prohibition in French.

@FranckDernoncourt It does (look it up in a dictionary). I think it's just MAE using stronger words than required, to scare people off of these zones. See Relaxed's comment.

@guillaume31 if they're using stronger words than required, then aren't they using "proscrit" to describe something other than a formal prohibition, and doesn't that mean that "proscrit" doesn't always denote a formal prohibition?

@phoog it's very possible that they used a rare term for a reason. However I suspect the intended effect is more to frighten people than to lessen its authoritativeness. As a normal citizen you're not supposed to have a university degree in French language to understand traveller advice.

@guillaume31 As to the meaning of "proscrit", I will leave that to native french speakers. Since this is an English language sites, such things should be made clear for the other readers.
